# Print only second part of a string split

Tags: python

Trying to split a string by `--` character and want to print the data after `--`.

Eg :

```
1.Cleveland-Elyria-Mentor    OH--17460
2.Dallas-Plano-Irving    TX  (MSAD)--19100
etc.
```

How to print only :

```
a.TX (MSAD)
  OH
```

and

```
b. 17460 
   19100
```

Code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import csv
   import re

   sample="""columnA,ColumnB,columnC
   1,Cleveland-Elyria-Mentor    OH--17460
   2,Dallas-Plano-Irving    TX  (MSAD)--19100
   3,ASJDFJKDJ-kD-JE       WA--21092"""


   open('sample.csv','w').write(sample)
   with open('sample.csv') as sample, open('final_output.csv','w') as output:
   reader = csv.reader(sample)
   writer = csv.writer(output)
   # discard input header
   next(reader)
   # write output header
    writer.writerow(['col1','col2','col3'])
    #process rows
   for row in reader:
        if row:
                for stsplit in re.split(r'--', row[1]):
                    writer.writerow([row[0], stsplit, row[1]])


   print open('final_output.csv').read()
```

Comment: Uh, I don't see any regex here...

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and tell us the expected output and what you get...

Comment: Is this not considered as regex - rsplit('--')?

Comment: @Viv, nope. It's standard string split.

Comment: **R**ight-`split` is not regex, no

Comment: and I fail to see the logic here: splitting your second line won't give you TX, not a chance: there's (MSAD) in between.

Comment: Adding code as per 2nd comment. and changing output to include (MSAD)

Answer (score 3):

`rsplit` isn't regex, so try actually using regex.

```
s = """1.Cleveland-Elyria-Mentor    OH--17460
2.Dallas-Plano-Irving    TX  (MSAD)--19100"""

import re

for line in s.split('\n'):
  match = re.search(r'(?P<state>\b\w{2}\b).*--(?P<zip>\d{5})$', line)
  print(match.group('state'), match.group('zip'))
```

Output

```
OH 17460
TX 19100
```

Comment: This is the best solution so far (and the one I'd accept if I were the OP). I recommend changing `found = re.findall(r'(\b\w{2}\b).*--(\d+)$', line)` to `found = re.findall(r'(?<state>\b\w{2}\b).*--(?<zip>\d{5})$', line)` so that you get tighter matching (states should only have two letter abbreviations, zip codes should only have 5 digits), and so that you get convenient named groups.

Comment: Python uses `(?P<name>...)`, and approach works as well, so updated.

Comment: @Viv `group()` is just a method that returns a string. `writerow([match.group('state'), match.group('zip')]` should work

Answer (score 3):

Taking the numeric values as an example:

```
import re
DOUBLE_DASH ="(?<=--)\d+"

def grab_numeric(line, pattern=DOUBLE_DASH):
    result = re.search(pattern, line)
    num = result.group(0) if result else None
    return num

with open("sample.csv") as inputs:
    for line in inputs:
        result = grab_numeric(line)
        print(result)
```

put your content into sample.csv and the code in test.py and run

```
python test.py
```

Output:

```
17460
19100
```

It is similar to grab `HO` and `TX`, just do some research by yourself and replace the `pattern` I provide. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly so: `split` creates a list with elements between the string that you pass as a sperator, `rsplit` does the same but scanning from the end of the string (which is important if you specify `maxsplit` argument for example). For you the difference is not important and you can use `split`, it will create a list of elements

```
['Cleveland-Elyria-Mentor    OH', '17460']
```

You want the `17460`, it's the last element of the list, so the code you need is

```
fipsplit = row.split('--')[-1]
writer.writerow(fipsplit)
```

Comment: This solution works for extracting the zip code after the `--`, but it will have issues extracting the state name because some states have following text in the example (e.g. `TX    (MSAD)` needs to return only `TX`). Using naive `str.split()` implementations makes this more challenging than using regular expressions.

Comment: Sure, I know that, but he wrote `Trying to split a string by -- character and want to print the data after --.`. That's why I wasn't sure what the OP meant. If he only wants the data after `--` which is the number, than this solution is fine :)

Comment: This gives me only the 0 of 17460. Not giving the entire 17460